# WPF application with Powershell code

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

I want to create WPF application (with ribbon menu) with powershell code inside this app.
I have created XAML, and in VS it is started properly. This is original code:

```
<RibbonWindow x:Class="ADUserMgmtTool.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="632.5" Width="931">
<Grid Margin="0,0,2,24">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Ribbon x:Name="RibbonWin"  SelectedIndex="0" >
        <Ribbon.Background>
            <ImageBrush/>
        </Ribbon.Background>
        <!-- Help Pane, located at the right-hand side -->
        <Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
            <RibbonButton x:Name="tempbtn" SmallImageSource="Images\help.png" />
        </Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
        <!-- Quick Access Toolbar - located at the upper-left corner -->
        <Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
            <RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
                <RibbonButton x:Name ="Save" SmallImageSource="Images\save.png" />
                <RibbonSplitButton x:Name ="Undo" SmallImageSource="Images\undo.png">
                    <RibbonSplitMenuItem Header="Undo 1" />
                    <RibbonSplitMenuItem Header="Undo 2" />
                    <RibbonSplitMenuItem Header="Undo 3" />
                </RibbonSplitButton>
                <RibbonSplitButton x:Name="Redo" SmallImageSource="Images\redo.png" >
                    <RibbonSplitMenuItem Header="Redo 1" />
                    <RibbonSplitMenuItem Header="Redo 2" />
                </RibbonSplitButton>
            </RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
        </Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
        <!-- Application Menu, located at the left-hand side (down arrow) -->
        <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonApplicationMenu KeyTip="F">
                <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Options" ImageSource="Images\options.png" />
                <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Exit" ImageSource="Images\quit.png" />
            </RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <!-- Ribbon Tab #1: Home -->
        <RibbonTab Header="Użytkownicy" KeyTip="H" >
            <!-- Home  group-->
            <RibbonGroup x:Name="UsersSearchGroup" Header="Szukaj">
                <RibbonMenuButton x:Name="UserSearchButton" LargeImageSource="Images\paste.png" Label="Szukaj" KeyTip="V" Width="111" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="UserSearchButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
            </RibbonGroup>
            <!-- Employee And Payroll group-->
            <RibbonGroup x:Name="UsersOperationsGroup" Header="Operacje">
                <RibbonMenuButton LargeImageSource="Images\personal.png" Label="Użytkownicy" KeyTip="V" Height="66" Width="108" />
                <RibbonButton x:Name="usersOperationMofifyButton" SmallImageSource="Images\save.png" Label="Modyfikuj" KeyTip="X" />
                <RibbonButton x:Name="usersOperationAddButton" SmallImageSource="Images\add.png" Label="Dodaj" KeyTip="C" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="usersOperationAddButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                <RibbonButton x:Name="usersOperationDeleteButton" SmallImageSource="Images\add.png" Label="Usuń"  />
                <RibbonButton x:Name="usersOperationResetButton" SmallImageSource="Images\add.png" Label="Reset hasła"   />
                <RibbonButton x:Name="usersOperationBlockButton" SmallImageSource="Images\add.png" Label="Zablokuj"   />
            </RibbonGroup>
            <!-- Employee And Payroll group-->
            <RibbonGroup x:Name="UsersReportsGroup" Header="Raporty">
                <RibbonMenuButton LargeImageSource="Images\personal.png" Label="Raporty"   Height="66" Width="108" />
                <RibbonButton x:Name="usersReportsLastLoon" SmallImageSource="Images\add.png" Label="Ostatnie logowanie"   />
            </RibbonGroup>
        </RibbonTab>
        <!-- Ribbon Tab #2: -->
        <RibbonTab Header="Komputery" KeyTip="I">
        </RibbonTab>
        <!-- Ribbon Tab #3: -->
        <RibbonTab Header="PageLayout" KeyTip="L" Margin="2,-1,-2,1">
            <ContentControl Content="ContentControl" Height="100" Width="100"/>
        </RibbonTab>
    </Ribbon>
    <Frame x:Name="frame" Content="Frame" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="418" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="892" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
    <Label x:Name="lbltest" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,5,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid> </RibbonWindow>
```

When I want to parse it as XML, I read in a lot of tutorials that I should delete all "x:" in XAML and delete from first line this code: "x:Class="ADUserMgmtTool.MainWindow"", so I deleted mentioned fragments.

Next, I run:

```
  Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework,WindowsBase,system.windows.forms

[xml]$XAML = $inputXML

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
```

and here I have error:

```
 Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Failed to create a ' 'SmallImageSource' from the text 'Images\help.png'."
 At line:1 char:1
 + $Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : XamlParseException
```

In case when I delete all parameters with Image and actions parameters with method names(e.g.  PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="usersOperationAddButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" ) , script will start sucesfully(also if I create WPF without ribbon - is started with success), but without these lines, it is unusable.

If anyone know how to resolve it ?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried setting a full path to the image: `<RibbonButton x:Name="tempbtn" SmallImageSource="C:\Form\Images\help.png" />`

Comment: Ohh, it helped :)
But if XML during this operation should be checking if *.png is really exist? I thougt that it only will create xml markups without checking. And I have another problem. Now, the error is appeared in line: Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Failed to create a 'PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown' from the text 'UserSearchButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown'."

Comment: What are you using `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` for?

Comment: This is line in xaml :                                                   
  ` <RibbonMenuButton Name="UserSearchButton" 
  LargeImageSource="full path\paste.png" 
  Label="Szukaj" KeyTip="V" Width="111" 
 PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="UserSearchButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />`

Comment: This is code for this method:                                                            
` private void 
UserSearchButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object 
sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
frame.Content = new usersSearchPage(); } ` it is used to load 
another frame content in main part of application

Comment: If you remove the PreviewMouse element from your XAML the form will load. I'm a bit confused, `private void....etc ` is C#, why are you loading the form in powershell? What is your ultimate target? If you want to handle events in powershell I can post an example.

Comment: Finally, I want to create tool for AD user managing (e.g creating new user). I want to type needed params in WPF forms and pass it to powershell and execute. This method will start after click Add button.

Comment: Are you using any C# code or is this going to be all done in Powershell?

Comment: At this moment I have only 2 action methods(after button click). I want to create C# apllication but after clicking button will be executed powershell commands, and e.g. datagrid will be filled by data returned by powershell commands

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are trying to load your xaml form in Powershell.
If you remove the references to `Preview Mouse` and call the `ShowDialog` method on `$form` your xaml form will be displayed.

```
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

What you actually seem to want is to run some Powershell code from within you C# application for that you need to use the `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces` class.

Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0)

Examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

If you are planning to use powershell to run Active Directory commands just remember that you will need to have Remote Server Administration Tools installed [RSAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2693643/remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-operating-systems) or Connect to a Domain Controller remotely.

The "Proper" way to work with Active Directories in C# is to use `System.Directoryservices` NameSpace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

Example form this [Site](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C)
Create new AD user in C#

```
public string CreateUserAccount(string ldapPath, string userName, 
string userPassword)
{
    try
    {
        string oGUID = string.Empty;
        string connectionPrefix = "LDAP://" + ldapPath;
        DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(connectionPrefix);
        DirectoryEntry newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add
            ("CN=" + userName, "user");
        newUser.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = userName;
        newUser.CommitChanges();
        oGUID = newUser.Guid.ToString();

        newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { userPassword });
        newUser.CommitChanges();
        dirEntry.Close();
        newUser.Close();
    }
    catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
    {
        //DoSomethingwith --> E.Message.ToString();

    }
    return oGUID;
}
```